# Как импортировать стили в NEXT js

Tags: scss, jsx, nextjs

Возникла проблема с компонентным импортом стилей. В реакте мы можем просто импортировать стили в виде:

```
import "./ComponentStyles.scss";
```

В Next js нет подобной поддержки.

Ранее была библиотека которая реализовывала подобную способность:
`@zeit/next-sass` но сейчас она устарела и выдает ошибки из-за отличий версии.

Использовать интегрированный в Next js подход в виде:

```
import styles from "./Categories.module.scss";


const Component = ()=>(
  <>
    <div className = {styles.classname>}/>
    <div className = {styles.container__element}/> // not expected
 </>
)
```

Не подходит из за неудобств с именованием классов. Кто как решает подобную проблему?
Ибо писать глобальные стили тоже не очень то и удобно

Answer (score 0):

Для всех, кто ищет рабочий ответ после extjs 11. Вы можете обратиться к этому [репозиторию](https://github.com/justgeek/nextjs-global-sass) или прочитать полную информацию в этой [статье](https://dev.to/justgeek/using-nextjs-with-sass-the-angular-way-3f7l)

Вот полный следующий конфигурационный код, который следует использовать

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([]);

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = withPlugins([withTM], {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    // Find and remove NextJS css rules.
    const cssRulesIdx = config.module.rules.findIndex((r) => r.oneOf);
    if (cssRulesIdx === -1) {
      throw new Error('Could not find NextJS CSS rule to overwrite.');
    }
    config.module.rules.splice(cssRulesIdx, 1);

    // Add a simpler rule for global css anywhere.
    config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: 'static/chunks/pages/[contenthash].css',
        chunkFilename: 'static/chunks/pages/[contenthash].css',
      }),
    );

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx/,
      use: [defaultLoaders.babel],
    });

    return config;
  },
});
```